.NET MAUI, hidding a collectionview when data is not available and showing it when it is available
I am implementing an ecommerce mobile app in .NET Maui. I have Trending-collectionviews and bestselling-collectionview. I would like to add a collectionview that will hold
new products-Collectionview and subsequently hide it when its not there in the HomePage.
How can I achieve this

You have to added a new CollectionView for new products to the HomePage. The visibility of the CollectionView is controlled via data binding, and based on there being new products. The ViewModel loads the products and determines to show or hide the collection view.

This solution will Hide/Show CollectionView, based on the List property has any items in it or not using the Converter.
You can create a Converter which returns true if there are items, False otherwise.
Suppose you name this converter as IsListHasItemsConverter
public class IsListHasItemsConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return !(value is IEnumerable<object> source) ? (object) false : (object) source.Any<object>();
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

Then in your Xaml, reference this converter into page's Resources.
Ex:
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <converters:IsListHasItemsConverter x:Key="IsListHasItemsConverter" />
</ContentPage.Resources>

And then in your CollectionView
<CollectionView
     IsVisible="{Binding MyProducts, Converter={StaticResource IsListHasItemsConverter}}"

NOTE: After Add/Remove item from the MyPrpducts, if this is not updating then try to RaisePropertyChanged to notify UI to invoke this converter in such events.
